# Приложение не совместимо ни с одним из ваших устройств в Google Play( даже с моим)

Tags: android, google-play, unreal-engine-4

Залил бэта версию игры на Play market,но она через магазин пишет не совместимо с моим устройством. Файл abb, boundle сделан в Android studio.Manifest переделывался перед билдом в Gradle и билды тоже.Apk билдился на Unreal Engine 4.Без Play Market всё работает.Вот манифесты для 64 и 32.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Gazflair3d.Nabuhator" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.0">
  <!-- Application Definition -->
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:hasCode="true">
    <activity android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:debuggable="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" android:configChanges="density|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:debuggable="false">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="UE4" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DownloaderActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="density|screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.EngineVersion" android:value="4.20.3" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.DepthBufferPreference" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bPackageDataInsideApk" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bVerifyOBBOnStartUp" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bShouldHideUI" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.ProjectName" android:value="Nabuhator20" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.AppType" android:value="" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bHasOBBFiles" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.BuildConfiguration" android:value="Shipping" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.CookedFlavors" android:value="ETC1" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bValidateTextureFormats" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bUseExternalFilesDir" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bAllowIMU" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <service android:name="OBBDownloaderService" />
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.LocalNotificationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.MulticastBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.10" />
  </application>
  <!-- Requirements -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <!-- Supported texture compression formats (cooked) -->
  <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
</manifest>


 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.Gazflair3d.Nabuhator" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.0">
  <!-- Application Definition -->
  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:hasCode="true">
    <activity android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.SplashActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:debuggable="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:debuggable="false">
      <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="UE4" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DownloaderActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard" android:theme="@style/UE4SplashTheme" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.EngineVersion" android:value="4.20.3" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.DepthBufferPreference" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bPackageDataInsideApk" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bVerifyOBBOnStartUp" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bShouldHideUI" android:value="false" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.ProjectName" android:value="Nabuhator20" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.AppType" android:value="" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bHasOBBFiles" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.BuildConfiguration" android:value="Shipping" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.CookedFlavors" android:value="ETC1" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bValidateTextureFormats" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bUseExternalFilesDir" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity.bAllowIMU" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    <service android:name="OBBDownloaderService" />
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.LocalNotificationReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.epicgames.ue4.MulticastBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.10" />
  </application>
  <!-- Requirements -->
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <!-- Supported texture compression formats (cooked) -->
  <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Спасибо за исправления,извиняюсь!